# Android MaterialButtonGroup Style Change

Tags: android, kotlin, material-components-android

I am in the process of building my first Android app and am running into an issue that should seemingly be very simple, but I'm at a loss on why it won't work. I am trying to use a `MaterialButtonGroup` where a selection is both required and only one option can be selected at a time. The XML for this is:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    app:selectionRequired="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:singleSelection="true"
    app:checkedButton="@id/btnCases">

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btnCases"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/Theme.MyApp.Toggle.Selected"
        android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.changeScanningMode(true)}"
        android:text="Cases" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btnUnits"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/Theme.MyApp.Toggle.NotSelected"
        android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.changeScanningMode(false)}"
        android:text="Units" />

</com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
```

The two buttons inside represent the either/or option (scanning cases or units with a handheld scanner). There are two styles I've created - `Selected` and `NotSelected` - which have a parent style of `OutlinedButton` from `MaterialComponents` and look like this:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp.Toggle.Selected" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton">
    <item name="android:checked">true</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/dark_blue</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="strokeColor">@color/dark_blue</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.MyApp.Toggle.NotSelected" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton">
    <item name="android:checked">false</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/dark_blue</item>
    <item name="strokeColor">@color/dark_blue</item>
</style>
```

When either button is selected, I am trying to essentially swap the styles by having the Fragment this lives on using an `Observer` to watch for a property change on the ViewModel so it can flip the styles. The ViewModel side works fine, but swapping styles does not. The code for changing styles looks like this:

```
val btnCases = binding.root.findViewById<MaterialButton>(R.id.btnCases)
val btnUnits = binding.root.findViewById<MaterialButton>(R.id.btnUnits)

when (it) {
    ScanningModes.CASE -> {
        btnCases.setTextAppearance(R.style.Theme_MyApp_Toggle_Selected)
        btnUnits.setTextAppearance(R.style.Theme_MyApp_Toggle_NotSelected)
    }

    ScanningModes.UNIT -> {
        btnUnits.setTextAppearance(R.style.Theme_MyApp_Toggle_Selected)
        btnCases.setTextAppearance(R.style.Theme_MyApp_Toggle_NotSelected)
    }
}
```

The desired result is to flip the styles completely, but after a lot of trial and error (which got me to the above), what ends up happening is when Cases is selected (on initial load and by flipping back and forth between it and Units), I get this (desired result):

[image: Cases Selected]

However, when I select Units, it does this:

[image: Units Selected]

This seems like it should be fairly easy to do, but I'm at a loss on how to accomplish this and hoping someone can assist.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Most of those attributes are not `TextAppearance` attributes, so they cannot be applied through `setTextAppearance()`; they're just ignored. The only one that is a `TextAppearance` attribute is `android:textColor`, which explains the observed behavior.

Comment: Thanks @MikeM.! That gave me an idea (since I'm only changing background color and text color), so I ended up using a combination of `setTextAppearance` and `setBackgroundColor` to achieve what I was after. Seems crazy that changing styles dynamically isn't supported, but it is what it is I suppose.

Comment: Whoops, I didn't realize you were trying to switch styles just 'cause of the state change. I shoulda read closer. Gabriele's got the proper way to do it. Sorry 'bout that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to switch style. You can just use one style with some selectors defining the **`android:state_checked`** state.

[image]

Something like:

```
<style name="App.Material3.Button.OutlinedButton" parent="Widget.Material3.Button.OutlinedButton">
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/app_m3_text_button_background_color_selector</item>
    <item name="strokeColor">@color/app_button_outline_color_selector</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/app_text_button_foreground_color_selector</item>
</style>
```

with `app_m3_text_button_background_color_selector`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/teal_200"  android:alpha="0.12"
        android:state_enabled="true" android:state_checked="true"/>

    <item android:color="?attr/colorContainer"/>
</selector>
```

`app_button_outline_color_selector`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:alpha="0.12" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:alpha="0.12" android:color="@color/blu500_dark" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:color="?attr/colorOutline" />
</selector>
```

`app_text_button_foreground_color_selector`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Disabled -->
    <item android:alpha="@dimen/material_emphasis_disabled" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface" android:state_enabled="false" />

    <!-- Uncheckable -->
    <item android:color="?attr/colorOnContainer" android:state_checkable="false" />

    <!-- Checked Buttons. -->
    <item android:color="@color/blu500_dark" android:state_checked="true" />

    <!-- Not-checked Buttons. -->
    <item android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Oh fantastic! While I have > 20 years of experience as a dev, being new to Android has definitely been a ride. Selectors seem like exactly what I'm after though. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing some additional details, I ended up solving the immediate problem by using `setTextAppearance` and `setBackgroundColor` since those are all I was really trying to change anyway. End result was this:

```
val btnCases = binding.root.findViewById<MaterialButton>(R.id.btnCases)
val btnUnits = binding.root.findViewById<MaterialButton>(R.id.btnUnits)

when (it) {
    ScanningModes.CASE -> {

        //change the text styles
        btnCases.setTextAppearance(R.style.Theme_MyApp_Toggle_Selected)
        btnUnits.setTextAppearance(R.style.Theme_MyApp_Toggle_NotSelected)

        //change the background colors
        btnCases.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.dark_blue))
        btnUnits.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.white))
    }

    ScanningModes.UNIT -> {
        btnUnits.setTextAppearance(R.style.Theme_MyApp_Toggle_Selected)
        btnCases.setTextAppearance(R.style.Theme_MyApp_Toggle_NotSelected)

        //change the background colors
        btnUnits.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.dark_blue))
        btnCases.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.white))
    }
}
```

It's kind of amazing that changing a style directly isn't supported, but I'm sure there are reasons. Thankfully I didn't have to change more, or I'd have been stuck!